# Does running an app on gke allow you to build a SaaS where customers use their own domains?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

If my application runs on GKE, will this give me the flexibilty to run a SaaS product where customers use their own domain names?

The one thing I need to confirm is that I want my customers to be able to use their own custom domains and point them (A-record and CNAME) to my service's IP address.

Example, say I am creating a SaaS product that is a CMS.  Customers will use their own domain name and point it to my service's IP like:

My SaaS runs on example.com

Customers will have their own domain and do the following DNS changes:

1. A record 1.2.3.4
2. CNAME to myservice.example.com

Will I need to do anything else to allow my customers to use their domain name?  This has to scale to tens of thousands of domains (in theory).

I'm not sure when I run a GKE cluster, do I get a static IP address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ingress resource, which is an HTTP(S) Load Balancer, to expose your application in GKE using a global static IP. If you have your application deployed, the next steps are:

- Create a global static IP.

> gcloud compute addresses create your-static-ip-name --global

- Once you have it reserved, create an ingress resource with:

`kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: your-static-ip-name`

You can get more detailed information in the official docs to [Configure Domain Names with Static IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress)